# Onedrive in readonly mode

Tags: readonly, onedrive

What is the best approach to configure onedrive to work in readonly mode in some machine/account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you writing an app to integrate with OneDrive? If so, you can grant the app the 'onedrive.readonly' scope so that it only has read access. More info here https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/auth/msa_oauth.md#authentication-scopes.

If you're not writing your own app, and you're wondering whether the official OneDrive app on your device can be configured to work in readonly mode, then that's not something that's supported.